# Is there a better way to handle SOAP POST response - traversing XML

Tags: c#, soap, xml-parsing

I've inherited C# code and am having some trouble with basic XML handling. I am more used to using JDOM in Java. I've also read many different tutorials, so far, none have helped.

The line of code `Console.WriteLine("at id "+xmlReader.Value.ToString());` will output the `id` twice, first with the value and then again with null.

```
at id 10805
at id
```

Is `XmlTextReader` not the best tool for this job? It seems to behave differently than my expectation, i.e. when I use `xmlReader.Read()` I expected it to read a complete XML element.

With JDOM I use e.g. `String userEmail    = messagePackage.getRootElement().getChildTextTrim("USEREMAIL");` is there something similar in C#?

The response:

```
<addAgentResponse xmlns="http://www.**********.com/soa/oi/ccma/service">
  <addAgentResult>true</addAgentResult>
  <agentLocalID>10805</agentLocalID>
  <errorMsg/>
</addAgentResponse>
```

The code handling the response:

```
response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(response.GetResponseStream());
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    switch (xmlReader.Name)
    {
        case "errorMsg":
            xmlReader.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("at error");
            if (xmlReader.Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                errorText = xmlReader.Value.ToString();
                failures = true;
            }
            break;
        case "agentLocalID":
            xmlReader.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("at id "+xmlReader.Value.ToString());
            break;
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an XmlDocument instead.  I usually go that route, unless I need to read a lot of documents very quickly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e48zttz7.aspx will give you the syntax for loading the xml from a stream.

Once you have the document loaded, you can use xpath to query the xml http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

ex.

```
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument;
   doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream);

   XmlNode node = doc.SelectChildNode("/AddAgentResponse/agentLocalID");
   if(node != null) { .... }
```